# Merge in h2 database, how to use it?

Tags: h2

How can I use merge with sepecify row in H2? Any answers are welcome and I appreciate

I mean how to merge with the values passed from outside.

Example: 
I wanna merge the row with name = "john" and id = "1" in table customer.

what the statement in this case

Comment: anyway, i have tried and got it. 
merge into table(id, name) key(id) values(?,?);

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you *really* mean the [MERGE statement](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#merge), but the documentation is on the web site.